# Finding distribution of random variable if X is exponential $(1)$

Tags: probability, complex-analysis, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let X be an exponential (1) random variable, and define Y to be the integer part of X+1, that is

$\hspace{15mm}Y=i+1$ if and only if $\hspace{5mm}i \leq X \leq i+1, i = 0,1,2,...$.

Find the distribution of Y.

My question: I have the solution, which is:

$\hspace{15mm}P(Y=i+1)\int_i^{i+1}e^{-x}dx = [-e^{-x}]_i^{i+1} = -e^{-(i+1)}+e^{-i} = e^{-i}(1-e^{-1})$

This is apparently a geometric distribution with $p = 1-e^{-1}$. If we plug  $p = 1-e^{-1}$ in to the geometric formula, we get

$\hspace{15mm}(1-e^{-1})(e^{-1})^{x-1}$.

I am not able to see how these two are equivalent (although I would imagine it has something to do with the properties of $i$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $i=0,1,2,3,\dots$, you have found that
$$\Pr(Y=i+1)=e^{-i}(1-e^{-1}).$$
Let $k=i+1$. You have found that 
for $k=1,2,3,\dots$, we have
$$\Pr(Y=k)=(1-e^{-1})(e^{-1})^{k-1}.\tag{1}$$
That's because $e^{-i}=(e^{-1})^i=(e^{-1})^{k-1}$.

Formula (1) is exactly the formula for the probability that $Y=k$, where $Y$ has geometric distribution with parameter $p=1-e^{-1}$.

**Remark:** The fact that the distribution of $Y$ is geometric can be found without the computation of an integral. For by the memorylessness property of the exponential, the probability that $X\ge k+1$ given that $X\ge k$ is just $\Pr(X\ge 1)$. So $\Pr(Y\ge k+1|Y\ge k)=e^{-1}$.